# Punctuation in Google Voice typing on Android 11 in other than english language

Tags: voice-recognition

I'm trying to use Google's voice typing but compared to iPhone it's really rude.

I'm already on Android 11. But it is still not able to detect my punctuation words, so everytime I want a `.` or `,` I need to stop the voice typing, switch back the keyboard to normal, enter the punctuation sign, and switch back to voice typing.

This requires as much effort that I turned off completely the dictation function.

Is it somehow possible to enter the word-mappings into the voice typing? I don't usually say "point" in a sentence for anything else but closing it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it somehow possible to enter the word-mappings into the voice typing?

That's not currently possible with Gboard  voice typing. Make sure to enable the auto-punctuation: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/244528/12202