# Google Voice typing punctuation - how to have it?

Tags: voice-recognition

I'm trying to use Google's voice typing, but it is not able to punctuate my sentences.
No matter I say "point", "dot" or "comma", it always writes it into my text.

Earlier I though this is only because I wanted to use the voice typing in other languages (not English). But now I'm trying to reach this functionality in English.

Is there any hidden tricks to enable the punctuation on Android 11 (Samsung)?

I found someone used the Swype keyboard which is obsolete now (since 2018). So really what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

On Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6 and Gboard keyboard:

[image]

This works great for me.

Comment: I don't have the GBoard, only the standard "Google Voice Typing": https://imgur.com/FQOu8lt

Answer (score 0):

> No matter I say "point", "dot" or "comma", it always writes it into my text.

I'm using English (US) and for me the voice input for punctuation works fine. It also works for me in German.

I noticed that you did not have the word "period" -- (aka "full stop" for brits)

These work fine for me:

- Period `.`
- Comma `,`
- Colon `:`
- Semicolon `;`
- Dash `-`

Check the language input settings, and try experimenting with different ways of pronouncing the punctuation.

This "faster / more accurate" setting might help as well:

[image]

PS: 99% of this answer was written with voice input.